# Git clone without parent directory fails in Nitrous.io

Tags: git, github, directory, fatal-error, nitrousio

`fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.` is the response to `git clone my-repo .` in my Nitrous.io box. I've deleted everything and running this from the root directory. Also, running `ls` gives me nothing so it is an empty directory.

Am I missing something or is this an issue with how Nitrous.io is setup itself?

[image: screenshot of my empty dir]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> running this from the root directory

Then, you must *not* use `git clone url .`, because `.` refers to an existing folder (here, your root directory).

Use:

```
git clone /url/to/my/repo: will create a 'repo' subfolder
# or
git clone /url/to/my/repo asubfolder: will create a 'subfolder'
```

Comment: is it possible to clone a repo's contents into root directory without putting the contents in a subfolder? ex: git clone url (repo has just an index.php file), ls now returns index.php, we're in root dir

Comment: @tejas-manohar not that I know of, even a subtree uses a subfolder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309 (http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).