# git - Including submodules into the main repository

Tags: git, dependencies, git-submodules, subproject

It's been about 6 months I used submodules for subprojects developed alongside a main project with a dev team.

```
- v-- Repository (developer(s)) --v

- Main project (dev team)
    - Sub project 1 (me)
    - Sub project 2 (me)
```

For several reasons now I'd like to consider my sub projects as regular files in the main repository.
So modifications in one of the sub projects ...

- ... should be committable from the main without having to commit and push from the sub project
- ... should still be committable from the sub project

The question is **How to disable these submodules** ?
I mean disable and not delete, as I need the files in the main repository

---

Here is what I did:

- Deleted `.gitsubmodule`
- Deleted the submodule sections from `.git/config`
- `rm --cached my_subprojects`
- `git add/commit/push`

Now when I try to merge this, the subprojects seem still considered as submodules as I still see

```
modified:   Sub project 1 (new commits)
modified:   Sub project 2 (new commits)
```

Comment: Did you follow the 7 steps from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/880584 to delete your submodule?

Comment: Well, I did not do the step 5 because I didn't have any `.git/modules` directory and neither the step 7 because I don't want to delete the files (but rather include them into the main repository)

Answer (score 2):

You still need to remove the [gitlink (special entry in the index which marks the folder as a submodule, and records the SHA1 for that submodule)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)

```
git rm --cached my_subprojects # no trailing /
```

The only other command is the `git submodule deinit my_subprojects` which takes care of the `.gitmodules`, `.git/modules` and `git/config`.

Then you can [add `my_subprojects` repo as a subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309).

Comment: Very useful details linked

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the existing files then don't forget to also remove the `.git` file from each submodule's path.

A submodule is defined in the following places:

- `.gitmodules` (not `.gitsubmodules` as you state above)
- `.git/modules` (the actual repository)
- `path/to/module/.git` (placeholder pointing to commit ID)
- `git/config`

If you've cleaned these all up then you should be fine, but make sure that branching / merging isn't biting you - `.gitmodules` and `path/to/module/.git` are under version control so may differ on different branches.

There's another issue with what you're trying to do that you may or may not care about - you won't preserve any of the commit history of your submodules. You can preserve the commit history by adding each submodule as a remote and then merging in appropriate remote branches.

Comment: I indeed care about committing in the sub projects. I guess you are talking about [subtrees](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging). That actually sounds to be what I'm searching for. I'll try that.