# push existing subdirectory of a repo to another remote

Tags: git, github

I have been pushing my entire project to a remote, but now I need to push a subdirectory within my project to a different remote. How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options are:

- [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) (to track the exact reference of a repo used by a subdir, using a [special entry in the index of the main repo: a gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309))
- [git subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309) (to manage only one repo, even if a subdir can be pushed to another repo)