# Manage nested independent git repository

Tags: git

I would like to manage two separate repository to assemble a project. Repo A contains the platform, repo B contains plugins I'm developing. Something like this:

```
- files repo A
  -app
  -src
    -files repo B
  -...
```

I would like to manage repo B git inside the installation platform, but the commands

```
cd src
git remote -v
```

give me the origin branch of repository A. Is possible to nest two different repository without using submodules? My development repo is B, and A is a reference platform repo that I want to manage separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is possible to nest two different repository without using submodules?

The [alternative to submodule is to use subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).
See an example in "[Apply gradle file from different repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309)".

---

But  **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** remains the usual way to manage this case: However, `B` files will be in a `B` folder.

If your `src` folder only contains `B` files, then you could do a:

```
cd /path/to/A
git submodule add url/B src
```

Comment: I'm developing under a platform developed with symfony so I would like to git only the bundles I'm developing. I don't know to start I have not a project under git, I need to put a subproject to git, I can create an empty remote repository but I don't know how to push only my bundles in that project...

Comment: Each submodule is its own git repo: you can start making sure your different repos are created. Then you can bring only the repo you need within a new parent repo with the `git submodule add` command that I mention.