# What are git subtree push assertions?

Tags: git, git-push, assertion, git-subtree, subtree

I know git subtree is a shell script and I can see the assert() function in it (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh). But I don't really know what it's doing and the one thing I know is every time I use git subtree push there's more and more of these "assertions". It's taking longer and longer just to push to my subtrees which seems ridiculous!

So, questions:

- What exactly are these assertions doing, and why does it have to start from the beginning of the assertion count every time I subtree push? * assuming these numbers are assertions.
- Is there a way to limit the number of these things? Something like git subtree pull --squash perhaps. I don't want to wait this much or that it'll break at some point when there's just too many.

Here's a sample output of a git subtree push command (notice how it does the endless assertions before checking that the repo even exists):

```
$ git subtree push -P prefix remote branch
git push using:  remote branch
1/    226 (0)2/    226 (1)3/    226 (2)4/    226 (3)5/    226 (4)6/    226 (5)7/
    226 (6)8/    226 (7)9/    226 (8)10/    226 (9)11/    226 (10)12/    226 (11
)13/    226 (12)14/    226 (13)15/    226 (14)16/    226 (15)17/    226 (16)18/
   226 (17)19/    226 (18)20/    226 (19)21/    226 (20)22/    226 (21)23/    22
6 (22)24/    226 (23)25/    226 (24)26/    226 (25)27/    226 (26)28/    226 (27
)29/    226 (28)30/    226 (29)31/    226 (30)32/    226 (31)33/    226 (32)34/
   226 (33)35/    226 (34)36/    226 (35)37/    226 (36)38/    226 (37)39/    22
6 (38)40/    226 (39)41/    226 (40)42/    226 (41)43/    226 (42)44/    226 (43
)45/    226 (44)46/    226 (45)47/    226 (46)48/    226 (47)49/    226 (48)50/
   226 (49)51/    226 (50)52/    226 (51)53/    226 (52)54/    226 (53)55/    22
6 (54)56/    226 (55)57/    226 (56)58/    226 (57)59/    226 (58)60/    226 (59
)61/    226 (60)62/    226 (61)63/    226 (62)64/    226 (63)65/    226 (64)66/
   226 (65)67/    226 (66)68/    226 (67)69/    226 (68)70/    226 (69)71/    22
6 (70)72/    226 (71)73/    226 (72)74/    226 (73)75/    226 (74)76/    226 (75
)77/    226 (76)78/    226 (77)79/    226 (78)80/    226 (79)81/    226 (80)82/
   226 (81)83/    226 (82)84/    226 (83)85/    226 (84)86/    226 (85)87/    22
6 (86)88/    226 (87)89/    226 (88)90/    226 (89)91/    226 (90)92/    226 (91
)93/    226 (92)94/    226 (93)95/    226 (94)96/    226 (95)97/    226 (96)98/
   226 (97)99/    226 (98)100/    226 (99)101/    226 (100)102/    226 (101)103/
    226 (102)104/    226 (103)105/    226 (104)106/    226 (105)107/    226 (106
)108/    226 (107)109/    226 (108)110/    226 (109)111/    226 (110)112/    226
 (111)113/    226 (112)114/    226 (113)115/    226 (114)116/    226 (115)117/
  226 (116)118/    226 (117)119/    226 (118)120/    226 (119)121/    226 (120)1
22/    226 (121)123/    226 (122)124/    226 (123)125/    226 (124)126/    226 (
125)127/    226 (126)128/    226 (127)129/    226 (128)130/    226 (129)131/
226 (130)132/    226 (131)133/    226 (132)134/    226 (133)135/    226 (134)136
/    226 (135)137/    226 (136)138/    226 (137)139/    226 (138)140/    226 (13
9)141/    226 (140)142/    226 (141)143/    226 (142)144/    226 (143)145/    22
6 (144)146/    226 (145)147/    226 (146)148/    226 (147)149/    226 (148)150/
   226 (149)151/    226 (150)152/    226 (151)153/    226 (152)154/    226 (153)
155/    226 (154)156/    226 (155)157/    226 (156)158/    226 (157)159/    226
(158)160/    226 (159)161/    226 (160)162/    226 (161)163/    226 (161)164/
 226 (162)165/    226 (163)166/    226 (164)167/    226 (165)168/    226 (166)16
9/    226 (167)170/    226 (168)171/    226 (169)172/    226 (170)173/    226 (1
71)174/    226 (172)175/    226 (173)176/    226 (174)177/    226 (174)178/    2
26 (175)179/    226 (176)180/    226 (177)181/    226 (178)182/    226 (179)183/
    226 (180)184/    226 (181)185/    226 (182)186/    226 (183)187/    226 (184
)188/    226 (185)189/    226 (186)190/    226 (187)191/    226 (188)192/    226
 (188)193/    226 (189)194/    226 (190)195/    226 (191)196/    226 (192)197/
  226 (193)198/    226 (193)199/    226 (194)200/    226 (195)201/    226 (196)2
02/    226 (197)203/    226 (198)204/    226 (199)205/    226 (200)206/    226 (
200)207/    226 (201)208/    226 (202)209/    226 (202)210/    226 (203)211/
226 (203)212/    226 (204)213/    226 (205)214/    226 (206)215/    226 (207)216
/    226 (207)217/    226 (208)218/    226 (209)219/    226 (209)220/    226 (21
0)221/    226 (211)222/    226 (212)223/    226 (213)224/    226 (214)225/    22
6 (215)226/    226 (216)fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git
repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Note: the command will only work if a subtree is already setup.

**Update:**

As suspected by @AndrewC and myself, these numbers (x)y/ may or may not indicate assertions. I may be assuming they do but in fact may very well be part of the git subtree split command fired by git subtree push. Whatever they are, the problem/question is the same: why do they keep increasing and how can I limit this because it's going to become unsustainable soon. I can't wait for 1000 or more *whatever-these-are* to complete every time I push a subtree!

Comment: Did you use subtree as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309?

Comment: Those don't look like assertions. An assertion would print out "assertion failed"

Comment: @VonC I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: @AndrewC They only print that out when they fail. These didn't fail.

Comment: Right, hence I question your assertion that the output you are seeing is from the assert() function.  I'd look at some of the `echo` statements that aren't part of the assert function.