# Migration from SVN to GIT, suggest, please, repository structure

Tags: git, svn

Currently we are using SVN and we have very specific repository structure. Project contains many modules, and we are building app for concrete customer using that modules and main solution file specific for engagement. So repository for app contains external references to modules (we prefer to use latest version in most cases) and app project. Structure is not very convenient. We want to migrate to GIT. Could you recommend structure in git to satisfy our needs and goal to build apps as lego blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each module can be converted in a separate Git repository.

You can then reference those modules as **[`git submodules`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)**, and make sure each [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) [follows a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309), which makes updating them in the parent repo very easy:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

The other approach would still uses one git repo per modules, but reference them as [subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) (also [presented here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/)).
You can see [an example in one of my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309).