# "git pull <remote> master" into a sub-directory

Tags: git, git-svn, svn2git

**Background**:

I'm trying to move a package from an SVN repo to a GIT repo, while preserving it's history.

**Steps**:

- I've used `git-svn` to generate a GIT repository for the SVN one.
- I'm following the steps mentioned **[here](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/)** to move the code from one GIT repository to the other, while preserving history.

I'd like to move that package into it's own sub-directory in the destination git repository. However, I'm stuck at this step: `git pull <remote> master --allow-unrelated-histories`

This pulls the code into the top level git directory. How do I pull that code into a sub-directory instead?

I've tried the following based on some SO answers, but that didn't work:

- `git pull -work-tree <working_dir> -git-dir <working_dir> <remote> master`
- `git pull -s subtree -Xsubtree=<path_prefix> <remote> master`

**Clean up step:**

The package will be maintained in the destination GIT repo, so I intend to:

- delete it from the SVN repo.
- And, also delete the intermediate GIT repo which will not be required once the package has been moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to import that SVN history into its own subfolder, you would need to import it into its own separate git repo.

Then you can

- add that git repo as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of the main Git repo: that would create a subfolder.
- Or, a better fit would be a **[subtree merging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309)**: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684503/6309).

Comment: Will that allow me to modify the sub-directory as if it belonged only to the existing Git repository? I've edited the question to clearly state what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @ShyamSunder Then that would be a subtree. See my edited answer and its references.

Answer (score 1):

That link you quote does not have anything to do with SVN.

Anyway, for a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories like yours that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly in one run if you like.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The link has nothing to do with git-svn or svn2git. I just gave a one line background about why I was interested in moving files from one Git repo to another preserving history. I've edited the question now to clearly state what I want to achieve, but thanks for the detailed notes about `svn2git` vs `git-svn`.

Comment: Even with your updated question the answer is the same. Use the right tool (the KDE `svn2git`) and you can easily achieve what you want with one step, producing a much better and faster result.

Comment: Thank you. Agreed that git-svn doesn't maintain the full history but my main concern here was to check out the code into a sub-directory from a different git repo. And `git-subtree` works for that use case.