# Managing chef cookbooks through git submodules

Tags: git, chef-infra

Currently, I am trying out managing all of my cookbooks via git submodules and I just want to make sure that I don't have any future issues with the way I am organizing it.

I took into consideration that from a manageability standpoint, it isn' popular to put all your repos in one basket (a single chef-repo) but I also didn't want to tell my developers that they are going to have to individually manage and pull/clone each repo before executing a chef run while testing their code (we are using berks and a chef server as well).

So the following git submodule strategy was my solution:

```
chef-repo < main >
├── chef-repo/LICENSE
├── chef-repo/README.md
├── chef-repo/chefignore
├── chef-repo/cookbooks
│   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/README.md
│   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/active-directory < submodule >
│   │   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/active-directory/Berksfile
│   │   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/active-directory/attributes
│   │   │   └── chef-repo/cookbooks/active-directory/attributes/default.rb
│   │   │   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/active-directory/libraries/cmd_helper.rb
│   │   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/active-directory/recipes
│   │   └── chef-repo/cookbooks/active-directory/resources
│   │       ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/active-directory/resources/computer.rb
│   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/example
│   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/java < submodule >
│   │   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/java/Berksfile
│   │   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/java/recipes
│   │   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/java/templates
│   ├── chef-repo/cookbooks/redhat_subscription_manager < submodule >
│   └── chef-repo/cookbooks/windows < submodule >
├── chef-repo/data_bags
├── chef-repo/environments
├── chef-repo/roles
```

I know that submodules aren't real popular either, so I just went with this approach so that developers could pull & clone the entire chef-repo as a whole, but they would be committing code to the individual repos.

Is there a better approach to doing this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Better approach? submodules are enough, even though you can check out **[subtrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770147/6309)** (that I [illustrate here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309))

But for submodules, especially if your contributors remains on the master branch of their respective submodule repos, don't forget the command:

```
git submodule update --remote --recursive
```

That will be enough to update all submodule to their latest commit on `master`.