# Should I remove tracking from my backend and frontend folders after I combine them into a new folder?

Tags: github, bitbucket

I have two folders, one is for the Frontend and one is for the Backend, both are being tracked and have separate repos.

I want to combine them into one "Project" folder and then track that and push to a new repo which obviously will just house the full App.

Should I remove the tracking from the respective frontend and backend folders before initializing a local repo on the "Project" folder?
Or does it not even make a difference in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you need to keep the history of those two repositories.

What you cannot do is simply add a commit those folders in a new parent repo, as it would only records "gitlinks" for the nested Git repositories

```
Project
  .git
  FrontEnd
    .git
  Backend
    .git
```

If you simply remove the nested .git folders... you are just importing subprojects files, without history

```
Project
  .git
  FrontEnd
  Backend
```

If you want to combine both repos in a larger one, you can follow "[Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories)", which uses [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), although this commands starts to be deprecated for [`git filter-repos`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

If you just want to reference them within your Project repos, you can add both [subrepos as submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
You also have the [subtree approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309). See "[Differences between git submodule and subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770147/6309)".

Comment: Thank you much! This response was more than expected and very helpful!

Comment: @AnelDrocic You are welcome. Don't forget to review your past question, and select an answer there as well, if said answer was satisfactory.