# Merge a subdirectory from Master to a branch

Tags: git

I have the most up-to-date code for a sub folder: "Folder-A" in the master. I have another branch: "Branch-A" that has same folder, but not up-to-date code. I am trying to merge that specific folder: "Folder-A" from the master to branch: "Branch-A". What is the git command to accomplish this? I would appreciate if someone can help me on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I merge a sub directory in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214906/how-do-i-merge-a-sub-directory-in-git). The result isn't actually a merge of your two branches; it's just overwriting Branch-A's version with master's version. So you'd lose any changes that Branch-A made to Folder-A.

Comment: I'm not clear on why a run-of-the-mill `git merge origin/master` won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two branches are local, follow these steps.

Switch to `Branch-A`:

```
git checkout Branch-A
```

Merge from `master`:

```
git merge master
```

If there were no merge conflicts, this is it. If there *are* merge conflicts, you will need to resolve the conflicts and commit changes. At this point, all changes from `master` will be available in `Branch-A`, including making the outdated folder `Folder-A` current.

If you want to just merge the contents of a subdirectory and *not* merge changes outside of that subdirectory, use one of the techniques outlined in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge).