# git: check if files in a single folder have changed in origin, and pull only the changed files if so

Tags: git

I have git repo in Bitbucket with hundreds of dirs and subdirs.  I'm writing a script (that calls git) to check if there have been any changes, but for this script I'm only interested a specific folder in the origin repo...not the whole repo.

Then, if there are any changes in that folder only, pull just the folder and all its contents.

What git commands would I use to do the check of the single folder in origin, and also what commands would I use to pull down just the folder?

Thanks

Comment: `git status folder_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pull a single folder. A pull is a fetch and a merge. Fetches can only get full commits. What you could do, however, is a partial merge as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214906/how-do-i-merge-a-sub-directory-in-git).

Comment: There is also submodules.