# How to merge a remote repo in a subdirectory of my project?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull

I want to merge a remote repo in a subdirectory of my project. I copied manually this remote project as subdirectory in my project some days ago and I modified it. Now there is a new version of it and I want to merge the new changes in my subdirectory without losing my modifications.

Structure:

```
myProject
    /mySubproject1
    /mySubproject2  <-- This one is the modified remote repo (from Github)
```

I already tried what is the following links, but without success:

- [How do I merge a sub directory in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214906/how-do-i-merge-a-sub-directory-in-git)
- http://bneijt.nl/blog/post/merge-a-subdirectory-of-another-repository-with-git

This is what I have done:

```
cd myProject    
git remote add -mySubproject2_github https://github.com/something.git
git merge -s ours --no-commit mySubproject2_github/master
git read-tree --prefix=mySubproject2 -u mySubproject2_github/master
```

But I get the following

> error: Entry 'mySubproject2/.something.yml' overlaps with
>   'mySubproject2/.something.yml'.  Cannot bind.

Is it possible what I want? Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: If you want to include this project inside your project *and* you want to keep it up-to-date, you may want to read up on "git submodules".

Comment: @larsks Am I able to modify the project and when I update the project, can I maintain the modifications?

Comment: @iker you can maintain a fork that pulls from upstream and maintains your changes. So you'd ideally need a separate repo.

Comment: A submodule is just a git repository...so, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Submodules which sometimes is a little bit messy, I used **Subtrees**. The subtree would be the project which I want to add to my "parent" project:

Here an example, we want to add the project nodejs-y-express from Github in our project.

Add the subtree to our project

```
$ git subtree add --prefix node_express_subtree https://github.com/codeheroco/nodejs-y-express-rutas master 
git fetch https://github.com/codeheroco/nodejs-y-express-rutas master
```

Update the project from the github

```
git subtree pull --prefix node_express_subtree https://github.com/codeheroco/nodejs-y-express-rutas master
```