# Git - How to pull exclude directory

Tags: git

My Git server has 2 branches:

> Foo and Master

In Branch **Foo**:

> Directory1
>
> Directory2

In Branch **Master**:

> Directory2

As you can see, in Branch **Master**, there is no **Directory1**.

Now, in directory 2 has changes in branch **Foo**

I am in branch **Master**, I would like to get changes from **Foo* without **Directory1**. How should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get just one file from another branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 1):

Git allows you to pull specific files and directories using `checkout`:

```
git checkout Foo -- Directory2
```

will pull just the `Directory2` folder from `Foo` branch. `--` tells git that everything that follows is a path spec.

If you want to do a true merge, follow one of the answers to this question: [How do I merge a sub directory in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214906/how-do-i-merge-a-sub-directory-in-git)

Comment: But I ever pull source code from "Foo" Branch. It occurred: fatal: invalid reference: Foo

Comment: That contradicts the part where you ask "...how do I get changes from Foo...?"

Comment: Actually, I just pull source from master branch, and my Co-Worker push source to his branch and now I pull source from his branch.