# Can't use git subtree pull

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm trying to pull from a remote into a folder in my repo. When using:

`git subtree pull --prefix my-local/folder my-remote master`

I'm getting the following error:

`fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

I read in an other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281079/git-subtree-error-fatal-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories) that I can use the option `--allow-unrelated-histories` but when I do I get `error: unknown option --allow-unrelated-histories` 
(I put the option last)

I'm using git version 2.10.1 and Windows 10

Any help or ideas on how to move forward with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git subtree error "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281079/git-subtree-error-fatal-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, I got it to work by adding the --squash option. This option merges the subtree changes as a single commit. I am not sure why this works but it obviously solves the history problem.

Comment: what do you mean by the --squash option? at what point in the script do you do that? using : git pull old-repo master --allow-unrelated-histories is getting the 'unknown option' error and putting --squash after pull or at the end is not working - my git version is 2.5.0 on windows 2010

Comment: after some digging I found - I had to add these extra steps---
1) git remote add old-repo <old repo directory>

2) git subtree add --prefix=<old repo directory> old-repo master --squash

3) git subtree pull --prefix=<old repo directory> old-repo master --squash

4) git pull old master --allow-unrelated-histories

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa && sudo apt-get update`
then use `--allow-unrelated-histories`