# Git error Not a valid object name, when merging subfolder of repository into subfolder of different repository

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to merge a subfolder of `master` branch of `repository2` into `master` branch of `repository1`, using the steps in this answer by @VonC - [How do I merge a sub directory in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214906/how-do-i-merge-a-sub-directory-in-git/5190916#5190916)

I perform the first two steps with success (adding the `repository2` remote, within the `master` branch of `repository1`, then performing an 'empty' merge from `repository2` to `repository1`). The structure of my repositories is like this:

```
repository2/master
  DataLib
    MessagingLib.V2
       .... files I want to merge into my repository1 branch

repository1/master
  MessagingLib
       .... files I want to merge the repository2 changes into
```

I have `repository1` `master` branch checked out. So for the `git read-tree`, I use this command:

`git read-tree --prefix=MessagingLib.V2/ -u repository2/master:repository1/MessagingLib`

But I get the error

`fatal: Not a valid object name repository2/master:repository1/MessagingLib`

What's the `read-tree` command I need?

**Update**

These don't work either:

`git read-tree --prefix=DataLib/MessagingLib.V2/ -u repository2/master:repository1/MessagingLib`

`git read-tree --prefix=DataLib/MessagingLib.V2/ -u repository2/master:repository1/master`

Answer (score 1):

This was complicated by the fact that I was attempting to merge the subfolder from `repository2` into a subfolder of a different name in `repository1`. I renamed my subfolder in `repository1` to MessagingLib.V2 (to match the name on `repository2`), then I could use:

`git read-tree --prefix=MessagingLib.V2/ -u repository2/master:DataLib/MessagingLib.V2`