# Managing multiple projects in the master branch in github

Tags: git, github, git-push

Suppose there are 2 projects in the master branch:

- Project A
- Project B

Now I have created a branch from `master` called `develop`, which has one project of the `master` branch: Project A

If someone has changed files in ProjectA in master branch, how can I pull those into `develop` branch?
I don't want ProjectB in `develop` branch.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [`git subtree split`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/13d7ab6b5d7929825b626f050b62a11241ea4945/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt#L101-L112) in order to isolate `projectA` folder from `master` into its own branch.
Then you can merge that branch into `develop`.

See "[How do I merge a sub directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60774244/6309)" for a concrete example of `git subtree split`.

Comment: I did following steps :

a) git checkout master
b) git pull
c) git checkout develop
d) git merge master
e) git push origin develop
This added Project A and Project B into develop. Is there anyway i can delete Project B from develop and merge it to master

Comment: @NKZ You can redo those steps, this time using git subtree split to isolate projectA in its own branch, before merging to develop. Or you can simply `git rm -r projectB` in develop in your current state.