# How do I merge a specific foler from "Their" repo into "my" repo where the directories are in different directories

Tags: git, git-merge, git-repo

I have a repository (my repository) that has a non empty directory, say its called "target". In this folder I have modified files from their repository's target folder. They have updated their files in their target directory, and I want to keep some of my modifications as it patches some issues but pull in their changes.

Say it looks like this:
**my repo structure**

```
- main.py
- non_main.py
- target/
- - file_1
- - file_2
```

**theirs**

```
- other.py
- something_else.py
- long/path/to/the/target/
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - file_1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - file_2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - file_3
```

and I have modified in my repo file_1 and file_2. They have added file 3 and possibly made changes to file_1 or file_2

I would like to merge in their changes to the target folder into my target folder. Like a merge but the repos look different but have 1 directory that we want to combine. I am only interested in combining the target folder

I have tried this: [How do I merge a sub directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214906/how-do-i-merge-a-sub-directory-in-git)
but seems like the prefix does not overwrite any files present in the original index. as it would give me error entry "file" overlaps with "file". Cannot bind. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [git merge-file](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file).

Suppose you have cloned the two repositories and checked out the expected branch in both.

```
# In your repository, create an empty file as the base file
touch foo.txt

# Merge their file_1 to yours
git merge-file target/file_1 foo.txt /path/to/long/path/to/the/target/file_1
```

Your `target/file_1` will be changed. If there is any conflic, just resolve it.

If you know what the real base file `foo.txt` is, the last common version of yours and theirs, you can use that version instead of the empty one.