# Can I interactively pick hunks from another git commit?

Tags: git

I'm looking for exactly the same behavior as

```
git add -i -p
```

But instead of composing a commit from my working directory, I'd like to compose my working directory from (parts of) a commit. How can I do that ?

My use case is that I have several distinct features that are grouped together in a single commit and I'd like to test them one by one

Using `cherry-pick -n` is not really satisfactory, since it leaves me with the dirty job of removing all the unrequired code. I'd really just like to pick the selected changes I want to test.

Comment: Well, the real solution is to split commits, so you won't be stuck with 'all the unrequired code' to remove in the first place. My money is on cherry-pick, not git reset  (always a bit dangerous)

Comment: Of course I will split the commits, I just need to find out *what* to split (and what to discard)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> Using cherry-pick -n is not really satisfactory, since it leaves me with the dirty job of
>   removing all the unrequired code. I'd really just like to pick the selected changes I want to
>   test.

The job may have been a dirty one before, but with the advent of [`git checkout --patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-p--patchlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203), you can now selectively discard changes, similar to `git add -p` for adding.

Comment: Oh, that's a sweet one. Exactly what I needed. Note that it might be wise to rebase/cherry pick the commit on top of your target commit if your target is not an ancestor of the cherry

Comment: Note: this doesn't really pick changes from a commit consistently, but pieces from a certain file state ! (possibly overriding / loosing other later changes)

Answer (score 11):

You could use `git reset --mixed HEAD^1` to revert the index, then pick the hunks you want with `git add -i`.

The `reset` will roll back the index to the previous commit (essentially un-committing whatever was the HEAD), but it won't touch the working tree. You can now stage the hunks you want, commit them and throw away the rest with a `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Comment: +1 As a very small note, `--mixed` is the default for `git reset`, so you could just leave that option out.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the great answer from Cameron Skinner, I will expand this a bit to include the case when you have *a branch with multiple commits*, perhaps merge commits, perhaps a lot of "noise" and you want to cherry-pick only very specific hunks from it. (which was exactly what happened to me today)

Follow these steps:

```
git checkout source-branch
git checkout -b cherry-pick-branch # Gives you a new branch based on source-branch
git reset --mixed master
```

This will leave you with a branch where all changes are in the filesystem, but nothing has been commited/staged. Then use `git add -p` to selectively add which parts you want to stage, and then commit & push as normal.

Answer (score 0):

> dirty job of removing all the unrequired code

If this is not acceptable,

```
git cherry-pick -n ...         # Starting from clean status
git reset                      # unstage
git add -p / -i [<pathspec>…​]  # add hunks interactively
git restore .                  # wipe the rest (at root dir)
```

, for example if you want to merge into uncommited changes or don't want to spoil time stamps, then using `git apply` like this may be a cleaner option:

```
git show <commit> | tee _.patch
edit _.patch                    # strip unwanted hunks
git apply -3 _.patch
```

(As long as `git cherry-pick` and `git apply` do not support `-p` directly)

Note: Methods like `git checkout / restore -p ...` do not consistently revert hunks from a specific commit but pick parts from a certain file state - possibly loosing changes in other later commits.