# Files changed between commits but with limiting file list to older commit

Tags: git, merge, diff

Situation: I have an old commit that I need to merge selectively with the latest commit. Some files have no changes and other files have significant changes that I need to review and merge selectively.

Let's say that the old commit `1` had files `A`, `B`, `C`.

The latest commit `5` has involved changing files `B` and `C` since commit `1` and also added files `D`, `E` and `F`.

So between commits `1` and `5` files `B` and `C` have changed, that is, running `diff` on `1:B` and `5:B`; and on `1:C` and `5:C` would show differences.

I need to get filenames `B` and `C` *only*.

That is, all files not belonging to `1` but changed or added until and including `5` should **NOT** show up.

Comment: You should clarify what "commit `1` had files `A`, `B`, `C`" means: only that they were present in the tree when commit `1` was made, or that changes to them were commit right in commit `1`.
  I assume the latter, while answers by @Michael Wild and @hlovdal assume the former.

Answer (score 2):

You might try

```
git diff --diff-filter=M 1 5
```

The available filters are

- `A`: Added
- `C`: Copied
- `D`: Deleted
- `M`: Modified
- `R`: Renamed
- `T`: Type changed (symlink, regular file, etc.)
- `U`: Unmerged
- `X`: Unknown
- `B`: Pairing broken

Refer to the [`git-diff(1)`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) manual page for all the details.

**Edit**:

If you are interested in **what** changed **how** between two commits, you can also use the `--name-status` option, which for every file that changed outputs one of the above codes. This option can also be used with `git-log` telling you what type of change was made to which files for each of the commits.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work after all (used another command in a script that just printed contents of commit "1" and thought this was the output).

Comment: Regardless of whether I used git diff --diff-filter 1 5 or git diff --diff-filter 5 1 it still displays ALL the modified files and does not limit output to contents of older commit.

Comment: I think you're missing the `=M` at the end of `--diff-filter=M`.

Comment: No, I just mistyped the example command, this is my actual command: git diff --diff-filter=M ce7dece9f43ced88325e12cf8b72cb324a14ac73 HEAD --name-status . I also tried reversing order of sha and HEAD and got the same number of files.

Comment: Try putting the `--name-status` before the commits, right after the `diff-filter=M`. The order of the commit arguments is irrelevant, as you're just asking which files are different. It would flip the left-hand and right-hand sides of the diff if you left out the `--name-status`. To confirm that it is actually working, verify that **only** files with status `M` show up. Then run with `--diff-filter=ACDRT' and check that you **don't** get files with status `M`.

Comment: I'm sorry, this STILL does not work. Perhaps it's because I run this in msys-git? (windows)

Answer (score 1):

To only consider the the files that are present in commit `1`, run

```
$ git ls-tree --name-only commit1 | xargs git diff commit1 commit5 --
```

Note that this will include files that were present in commit 1 but are deleted in commit 5 (which will show up as deleted files in the diff). If you want to avoid that, find the common subset of files:

```
$ git ls-tree --name-only commit1 > all-files-in-commit1
$ git ls-tree --name-only commit5 > all-files-in-commit5
$ comm -1 -2  all-files-in-commit1 all-files-in-commit5 > common-files
$ xargs git diff commit1 commit5 -- < common-files
```

Comment: Those number are unrelated. `git ls-tree ce7dece...` shows 299 because that is how many files present when you check out that commit. `git show ce7dece...` shows 16 because that is the number of files changed compared to the parent commit.

Answer (score 0):

Try (using SHAs `1` and `5` as in your example):

```
git diff 1 5 $(git diff --raw --no-commit-id --name-only -r 1~1 1)
```

Or more comfortably, so you only have to type every SHA once:

```
c1="1"; c2="5"
git diff $c1 $c2 $(git diff --raw --no-commit-id --name-only -r $c1~1 $c1)
```

How it's meant to work: The first git diff compares the two commits. The second generates a list of paths to limit the comparison to. This list is generated by comparing which files changed between your older commit `$c1` and its parent `$c1~1`. (This also works when specifying something like the tenth-last commit using `c1="HEAD~10"`, since `HEAD~10~1` is a valid tree-ish in git, equivalent to `HEAD~11`.)

The subshell uses `git diff --raw` to als work for merge commits. Else we could use `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $c1`, which automatically compares a commit with its parent.

**TODO:** Not yet fully functional. At times it works, at times I get "fatal: ambiguous argument '<filename>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, with your "latest commit" `5` you refer to `HEAD`, you could also use this different strategy for your task. I found it to be the most workable so far:

1. Apply your changes from the old commit to your staging area, without committing (`-n` = `--no-commit`):

   ```
   git cherry-pick -n <commit>
   ```
2. Unstage all the changes you just made:

   ```
   git reset
   ```
3. Compare what these changes are, relative to your last commit:

   ```
   git diff HEAD
   ```
4. Selectively add the changes you want:

   ```
   git add -p
   ```
5. And finally make the new commit:

   ```
   git commit -m "commit message"
   ```

Source: Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1526093/1270008).