# Merge selected changes in a file stepwise

Tags: git

I've made some changes to a file on a git branch (let's call this branch `experimental`). I'd now like to merge in some, but not all of the changes I made to this file into my `development` branch. Is there a way to go through each change within this file step-wise and manual tell git to merge a particular change or ignore it?

Comment: these changes are on a commit with other changes?

Comment: yes, these changes are on another commmit in my `experimental` branch. I now want to merge only select changes from `experimental` into `development`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [partly cherry-picking a commit with git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526044/partly-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the changes in experimental are already at a commit granularity, then you want

```
git checkout development
git cherry-pick <sha ID>
...
```

If your changes to experimental are more random smaller commits *or* one huge commit, then I'd follow this flow:

```
git checkout development
git merge experimental --squash --no-commit
```

This puts *all* the changes into your index
Then add interactively:

```
git add -i
```

This presents a pretty basic UI where you can initially unstage everything, then pick in hunks, and even edit hunks on a line-by-line granularity.
Once you're satisfied with what you have in staging,

```
git commit
```

You still have random changes in the 'modified' state, basically (1 - what-you-committed).
You want to get rid of this using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```