# Remove deleted files from a commit in git repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a commit in gerrit with three files in which there are two deleted files, But i don't want to merge those deleted changes. I have tried all sort of things with resetting those files, but as i am just checking out the change from gerrit, It doesn't seems to actually do anything.

This i have found on lot of places:

```
git add -u
git reset HEAD path/to/file
git commit
```

but didn't work. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the files via git.

```
 git rm path/to/filename
```

I did this test. Clone an existing git repo to deleteme.
Removed the README file from the repo and commit the changes.

```
 $git clone /path/tomy/gitrepo deleteme
 $cd deleteme
 $rm README
 $git commit -a


 # Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
 # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
 # On branch master
 # Changes to be committed:
 #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
 #
 #       deleted:    README
 #
```

~
~
~
~

Comment: How will this work when I dont even have that file in current checked out branch

Comment: You can still call this command on the deleted files. What if you just do git commit -a? Do you see the removed files in the log?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do. is cherry-pick the change-set from gerrit.
And than in interactive fashion merge only the file you want.
More details:
[partly cherry-picking a commit with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526044/partly-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git)