# Can I add changes to staging area from another branch?

Tags: git, shell, version-control, dvcs

I have two branch,

- master
- new-features

New features have a commit I want to add to master but I want the control how much I want to merge.

I would like the option to add/reject changes for each line. Similar I can do with `git add -p`

I have searched a lot probably I was searching wrong term. This seems quite obvious task.

Comment: There's only one staging are in a working directory, the isn't one per branch.

Comment: @choroba: in fact, there's only one *standard* staging area (aka "the" index), but you can define your own temporary index using the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE`. That's not a useful thing to do for this particular task. :-) But unfortunately it's something one needs to know in order to explain some odd corners of `git commit -a` and commits with `--only` or `--include`.

Comment: @torek You can have multiple working directories with one local repository, each of which will have its own index. So you’re both right :P

Comment: @poke: he said one "in a working directory" (one per work-tree is how I put it, when I talk about `git worktree add`). But, for example, `git commit file.ext` when you've staged a *different* version of `file.ext`, wipes out your staged version after committing the work-tree version, and the reason for that is that it copies the standard index to a temporary index, adds the work-tree version of `file.ext` to the temporary index, commits, and then *copies back* the newly-committed `file.ext` from the temporary index to the standard index. (I'd argue that this is a bug.)

Comment: Another way to see this temporary-index behavior is to use `git status` while paused in the editor on a commit being made with `git commit -a`, `git commit file.ext`, and the like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [partly cherry-picking a commit with git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526044/partly-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `git cherry-pick` with the `-n|--no-commit` option and then interactively select what to commit:

> **git cherry-pick**
>
> ...
>
> `-n`, `--no-commit`
>
> Usually `git cherry-pick` automatically creates a sequence of commits. This
>   flag applies the changes necessary to cherry-pick each named commit to your
>   working tree and the index, **without making any commit**. In addition, when
>   this option is used, your index does not have to match the HEAD commit. The
>   cherry-pick is done against the beginning state of your index.
>
> This is useful when cherry-picking more than one commits' effect to your index
>   in a row.

So the sequence of commands will be the following:

```
git cherry-pick -n <commitid>  # merge commitid into the index and working-tree
git reset                      # clear the index
git add -p                     # selectively add merged changes to the index
```

Alternatively, you can use `git reset -p` to **remove** undesired hunks from the staging area:

```
git cherry-pick -n <commitid>  # merge commitid into the index and working-tree
git reset -p   # interactively remove from the index changes brought by commitid
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I tried with `cherry-pick` before but I didn't used `-n` flag. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7):

I think you can try to use patch file.

To create patch file run:

```
git checkout master
git diff ..new-features > patch.diff
```

In file `patch.diff` you have difference between branches master and new-features.

Now you can apply patch file, run:

```
git apply patch.diff
```

Now you can manage your changes in any desired way.

Comment: @Leon Yes, i meant patch. Thx you! I've already fixed this typo.