# How to merge a branch to master without taking features that aren't production ready?

Tags: git, merge, git-flow

I've checked lots of questions here in Stack, but didn't figure out how can I use the Gitflow Workflow in my team.

Here are our branches:

[image: workflow]

In my team we have three main branches: **master**, **test** and **dev**. All feature branches are being branched off of *dev*. Once they're a somewhat stable we branch them back in *dev* (we're maintaining that dev server to allow some non-developers to perform some tests before send to the customer Q&A).

So, when the feature is stable enough to go to the customer test, we merge the branch *dev* to the branch *test*. Once approved, the *test* branch is merged into *master*.

My issue is: in some cases we could have 4 different branch features that were merged into *dev* and then into *test*. But, for some reasons, one of the features in test should go to production, while the others 3 should wait for customer validation.

How can I send to prod (merge into *master*) only the approved feature, and keep the others 3 in *test* without carrying all its commits during the merge?

Comment: Use [cherry picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Comment: To clarify, you have features 1, 2, 3, 4, all of which made it to **dev** and **test**. Now you only want feature 4 to go from **test** to **master**, keeping everything else as-is?

Comment: Also, that merge with two purple dots and a yellow dot going into another yellow dot looks a bit shady. I'm not sure you can merge three commits together like that, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, in this case I'd like to send only the feature 4 to production and keep 1,2,3 yet into test waiting for a new release. (Just to clarify that the feature 1, 2, 3 and 4 could have many commits each one).

Comment: OK. One final question. Do the fixes that happen in **dev** and **test** get commited on a per-feature basis. I.e., can you point to a set of commits in **test** and say, these are the exact commits that represent feature 4 with all modifications that need to go to master?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm quite sure that the answer is yes. Once we're always using merge with *--no-ff*, I can figure out the exact point where each feature was branched into **test**. So, each bunch of commits among the merges should belongs only to each feature.

Comment: @MadPhysicist OT but that's kosher; it's called an octopus merge. [See this infamous 66-parent example from the Linux kernel](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=139033182525831).

Comment: @WederRibas this is a classic use case for `git cherry-pick`: identify the commits on `test` which introduce feature 4 and cherry-pick them into `master. From the man page: "Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each."

Comment: @Pockets. That's just neat. But I'd hate to be anything but a spectator :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a standard use-case for [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). This is a command that lets you apply selected commits and ranges of commits to a different branch. Since you said that you know exactly which set of commits you need to apply, it is a perfect tool for the job.

As of git 1.7.2, you can cherry-pick a range of commits. Say feature 4, which needs to be applied to master, is represented by commits with SHA1s 12345 through abc123. Then you just do

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick 12345^..abc123
```

The first commit must be the earlier one. `^` takes care of the fact that the starting end is exclusive in the range. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/2988730 for details.

For prior versions of git, you would have to process each commit individually:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick 12345
git cherry-pick df998
...
git cherry-pick abc123
```

If it turns out that you do need to break up some of your commits, use `git cherry-pick -n` to check out the patch and then use `git add -p` to get the chunks you want out of it, as described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1526093/2988730).

It is also possible to use `git rebase --onto` to accomplish the same task. This has the advantage that you can do it interactively, i.e., select the commits, modify their messages and have more control over the content than with cherry picking. The answer linked above explains how to do this in detail.