# Git commands to save current files in temporary branch without committing to master

Tags: git

Suppose I have a local Git repo and some uncommitted changes. Because the changes might be very messy, I don't want to commit to my branch yet, but I do want to test it on the cloud.

I'm seeking a sequence of git commands that can:

1. Commit the "messy changes" to another branch, such as `mymessydev`
2. `git push origin mymessydev`.
3. Switch back to master branch with the same uncommitted changes, as if nothing has ever happened.

Comment: Did you checked this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch/1519032#1519032

Comment: When you have a lot of branches, using `stash` may get complicated. An alternative is `git worktree` command, which has some drawbacks as explained in its man (and not all tools support it correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you're on the master branch with the messy changes. Then,

```
git stash
git checkout -b messybranch
git stash apply
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git push origin messybranch
git checkout master # clean master
```

At this point, you won't lose these changes as they're already pushed on `messybranch`. In order to get these changes back to `master`, you could either merge `messybranch` or `cherry-pick` the commit on `master`.

```
git merge messybranch
```

OR

```
git cherry-pick #commit
```

`cherry-pick` or `merge` commits your changes but if you'd like them to be staged and not committed, you can do

`git reset head~1`

Comment: Looks like `cherry-pick` will commit the messy change. I found another post that can unstage the cherry-pick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1526093/3453033

Comment: edited my answer to remove the commits and unstage on the `master` branch - let me know if that works for you.

Comment: looks like should be working now, I'll go ahead and mark your answer as accepted anyway. Thanks!

Comment: see my new answer

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a python script to automate this process. It works even for untracked files!

First install the python binding: `pip install gitpython`

```
import sys
from git import Repo
import time


def save(temp_branch, repo_path='.'):
    repo = Repo(repo_path)
    git = repo.git
    work_branch = repo.active_branch.name

    ret = git.stash()
    is_stash = not 'No local changes' in ret
    # delete the temp branch if already exist
    try:
        git.branch('-D', temp_branch)
    except:  # the branch doesn't exist, fine.
        pass
    git.checkout('-b', temp_branch)
    if is_stash:
        git.stash('apply')
    git.add('.')
    try:
        git.commit('-m', 'temporary save ' + time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    except:
        print('no temporary changes to push')
    git.push('-f', 'origin', temp_branch)
    git.checkout(work_branch)
    git.cherry_pick('-n', temp_branch)
    print(git.reset('HEAD'))


save(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b mymessydev                         # switch to new branch based here
git commit -am 'smoketest commit on WIP messydev'  # commit to that
git push origin messydev                           # push it
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master            # pretend the above never happened
```

This relies on only one unfamiliar core command, `git symbolic-ref`. A vanilla `git commit` *always* updates the `HEAD` ref (aka `@` almost everywhere).

Git has a "symbolic ref" facility that makes one ref an alternate name for another, one way to describe what it does is, it "attaches" that one ref to the other.

When you `git checkout` a branch by its short name, the convenience commands make `HEAD` a symbolic ref to that branch. That is literally all there is to having a branch checked out: the `HEAD` ref is attached to the branch-tip ref, any updates to `HEAD` will instead update that tip ref, anyone resolving `HEAD` will get the branch tip commit, anyone looking for whether `HEAD`'s attached to some branch tip with `git symbolic-ref HEAD` or some convenience command that does that for you will see the link,