# Git: How to raise a selective Pull Request containing only subset of files (not commits)

Tags: git, pull-request, git-flow

Following normal `gitflow`, I have a `master` branch from which I have forked a `feature` branch for development purposes. In the `feature` branch, I have done tons of changes (added new files) and now need to merge back to `master`. Please note that these changes in the `feature` branch has happened over several weeks containing hundreds of commits.

However, due to requirements, I am allowed to take a **sub-set of files**, which have been edited/added across multiple commits.

Question is - how do I raise a pull request from `feature` to `master` containing the above sub-set of files only and ignore any other files that may have been added/edited?

Please note that its not possible to do a GIT `cherry pick` of commits, because

1. There are hundreds of commit in the `feature` branch
2. Any of these commits can contain the files to be merged back alongwith files that don't have to be merged back.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing.  Git works on a *commit-by-commit* basis.  If the commits you have are not the ones you want, you must make new, different commits.

Generally, the way you might do this is to create a new branch whose current commit is the same starting point as the set of commits that you *don't* like (e.g., also starting at the tip of `master`) and then explicitly extract specific files from specific commits, as in [blami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64008097/1256452).  Note that you do not need `git commit -a` here.  I personally consider using `git commit -a` a bad habit because it leads you into trouble when you create *new* files.

(Note, by the way, that every commit contains *every file*, or more precisely, every file Git knew about at the time you, or whoever, made the commit.  These are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format, so the fact that the *last* commit in `feature` might have the same copies of the same files as hundreds of earlier commits in `feature` means that the de-duplication has saved lots of space.)

Comment: Thanks for call on `git commit -a` bas habit. I updated my answer and removed it from my example.

Comment: @blami: not really a problem - it's a bit surprising, at first, that this kind of `git checkout` writes the files into both Git's index and one's working tree, and the new (since Git 2.23) `git restore` has options to pick which of those two (or both) to write, so if you only write to your working tree, you'd need to run `git add -u` or equivalent, which the `-a` shortcut saves. The thing that catches people here is that `git add -u` *doesn't* add totally-new files, and hence neither does `git commit -a`...

Answer (score 4):

You want to create a new `feature2` from `master` and include only your sub-set of files in it, create PR from it, have it tested and reviewed.

To create such branch from certain files (not commits) in existing branch:

```sh
git checkout -b feature2 master 
# optionally git rm any checked in files in master that shouldn't be there (were removed in feature)
git checkout feature -- <path> [ <path> ... ]
git commit
```

where `<path>`s are paths to subset of files in original `feature` branch you want to include.

Other option could be to `cherry-pick` but for that you'd need to identify commits where those files were added to `feature` branch and probably do [partial cherry-picks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526044/partly-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git).

Comment: When I try this `git checkout feature -- <path>`with the path of a file which is in the `feature` branch but not in the `feature2` branch, I get : `error: pathspec '<path>' did not match any file(s) known to git`