Can Azure DevOps Pull request feature allow selected files to be merged from one branch to another. ? If not how can we achieve this?
Can Azure DevOps Pull request feature allow selected files to be merged from one branch to another. ? If not how can we achieve this ?
Tried cherry picking, dint help..
I just want to exclude environment specific config files from merging to another branch.
Unable to achieve this requirement.

This question is similar to: GitHub: accept part of pull request by changed files. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/64008131/558486

Git doesn't merge based on files, it merges commits.

@RuiJarimba That's aboout Git/GitHub, this is about Azure DevOps (which is a different platform from GitHub, and may not use Git at all).

@TylerH the question is about Git pull requests. No matter which platform you use, the answer is the same: Pull request are atomic, you cannot accept few files in request. Either its all or nothing.

Currently, there isn't such feature can allow only selected files to be merged from one branch to another. As mentioned by @Rui Jarimba and @Daniel Mann, this is the way Git works. Git merge will combine multiple sequences of commits into one unified history.

If you want such a feature in Azure DevOps... - would it even make sense such as feature? The way I see it this is related to how Git pull request works, not an Azure DevOps specific issue.

@RuiJarimba Agreed. This is an issue with workflow, not something that can be implemented as a feature. Git doesn't work the way they want it to work.
