# Cloning From Reset Master Using GIT GUI

Tags: git

I would like to reset the master branch to a previous commit so that if someone uses the GUI (and ONLY uses the GUI), they can do a simple clone a get the reset version. I did a "Visualize Master's History" then right-clicked on the commit I want to reset to. I can then click "Reset Master Branch to Here", and could then get this commit this way. But when someone just launches the GIT GUI and does a "Clone Existing Repository", I would want this version to show up, and not the subsequent commits.

Reasoning: I've got some SW Quality folks who have a documented SOP that says to do things this way, and I'd like to maintain it if possible.

So is there anything I can do to make this the version that is "cloned" via the GUI without scrapping my subsequent commits?

EDIT: The best way to do this, I suspect, would have been to branch from my previous working version (what I'm trying to reset to) until I was sure the changes made on my branch were ready for commit back to my master branch. Before the branch was merged back to my master, a clone via the GUI would only have pulled the master version. Right?

Comment: Sounds like the "right" answer would be a brick^H^H^H^H^Hclue-bat for some SOP writers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have reset your branch, you need to force push it, in order for other to see the same history.
See "[EGit on Eclipse: How to git push --force?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12302449/6309)" (using a [push ref spec](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Ref_Specifications) including the option "force Update")

That will work for other user cloning your repo for the first time: they will see your branch as you reset it.

But that means other users who have already cloned your repo and will be fetching from it will have to reset their own local branch to the one they have fetched.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. For those wondering, the syntax was git push remote origin --force.