# Does resetting fork with upstream affects pull requests created?

Tags: git, github

Please find below steps that I did on forked repo:

1. I have created the fork of famous OSS project on Git Hub
2. Done some changes, raised PR from **master** branch from forked repo to upstream, the PR is approved and merged with rebase/squashed commits
3. Now, I want to work on another feature, unfortunately after doing
   `git merge upstream/master`, the master in forked repo is ahead of upstream due to merged commits

To reset fork, I am doing:

```
git reset --hard upstream/master  
git push origin master --force
```

If I would have created feature branch and PR from that branch, deleting that branch would be easy.

However, since it is done from master branch, does it affect my first PR or is it safe to reset fork after submitting PR?

Comment: You can create a new branch on where master is before doing the reset you show above. That'll be your feature branch.

Comment: Can't I reset master branch?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm assuming you want to mark your changes with a branch first.

Comment: Also, why are you working off master in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I realized later that to better use feature branch. Now, all I want to reset fork (master branch) without affecting completed PR

Comment: I'm  not sure I fully understand. You have three repos: upstream is the project, origin is your fork on GitHub, and local is your clone of origin. You made a squashed commit on local/master, pushed it into origin/master, whence it got merged into upstream/master. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Could you draw a little sample history graph perhaps? Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/51270796/2988730.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since it is done from master branch, does it affect my first PR?

No, your first PR was approved and merged.

> or is it safe to reset fork after submitting PR?

Yes, you can force push `master`.
And then make a dedicated feature branch for your new PR.