# Git - Merge vs rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

I have had a look at [When do you use git rebase instead of git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge)
.

But I'd like to be sure about which solution to choose in this case:

I want to implement a new feature on `master` so I branch it to a new Feature branch.
I do 10 commits on Feature while someone else does other commits on Master.

My question is if I want to keep my branch apart from Master for testing purposes, but I need to test it with the new Master commits integrated.
So, should I merge Master into Feature (and not Feature into Master which would apply my modifications on master before my testing) or do a `rebase`?

Comment: That's up for a debate. I'd do a rebase.

Comment: The top answer in the link you looked at provides a clear recommendation to rebase in your use case.

Comment: In the future, please use more descriptive titles that more clearly explain what the problem is that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not create a new branch to test the merged version?  For example:

```
git checkout -b test-merged-feature master
git merge my-feature
[... do your testing ..]
```

There's no particularly reason to do a rebase here, but if you haven't already pushed your feature branch, that'd be fine as well.  These questions are partly about how you would want your history to look - some people don't like seeing lots of merges; some prefer it as a way of keeping track of which commits contributed to a particular feature.

Comment: I suppose having a "dev" branch to test the features together and then putting it on master for production would be a good practice in that case ? So the merge vs rebase question is simply about how you want your commits history to be ?

Comment: I agree on this option (merge in a new branch), so +1. But I still advocate for a rebase in my answer below.

Comment: @user2316341 a "dev" branch makes sense if you have to integrate (merge) several Feature branches, to see if they all work together. But if you have only one Feature branch at a time... it adds complexity for little gain.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have already pushed your branch (and you know others have cloned your repo), I would still do a rebase, as I mentioned in my own answer of "[git rebase vs git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804178/6309)".

Test or not, I usually do a rebase each time I update my local repo (git fetch), in order to ensure the final merge (`Feature` to `master`) will be a fast-forward one.

So it isn't just about how your history look, but it is mainly about making sure what you are developing isn't based on an old version of `master`, and keep working against the latest evolutions done in `master` over time.

Comment: So you say that I should always do rebase most of the time, but not if I have already pushed my branch. Why is that ? What is the problem of having already pushed the branch ?

Comment: @user2316341 a rebase rewrite the history of SHA1. You would have to `git push --force` in that case to replace the history already pushed by the new one generated by the rebase. If noone is using your branch, this isn't a big deal, and rebase is by far the simplest and safest solution, over adding artificially a merge to an intermediate branch.

Comment: @user2316341 see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8940299/6309 as an example of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In workflows I'm familiar with, there is a trunk, and integration branch(s), and feature branches

I have been rebaseing towards the 'derivative' branches. (by derivative branches, I mean the direction AWAY from the trunk), and merging towards the integration branches.

I like that I'm always working in a branch that has the same history as the branch I'll be integrating with. I like that the merge becomes a fast-forward, so, I know that what I just merged is exactly the same as what I just tested in my branch.

Answer (score 0):

When 2 developers commit to the same repo (this will make a conflict) you can merge the 2 commits by creating a merge commit or you can rebase 1 of the commits (yours) on top of the other commit. it’s always better to rebase instead of generating a merge commit.