# Error in pushing branch after git rebase

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I am new to Git. I have cut my branch from master as follows:

```
git co master
git fetch
git pull origin master
git co -b my_branch
```

Now I have been working on my that branch for past one week. Now it is ready to be deployed. So
I did

```
git rebase master
```

But after rebasing while I am trying to push my branch, it keeps giving error saying I have to pull first. I finally pushed my branch as follows:

```
git push -f origin my_branch
```

I alone working on this branch. So every code on this branch has been pushed by me only. Then how it's giving such error, I don't understand. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using git-rebase imply rewriting commits. Since commits have changed, git push can't do a fast-forward anymore, so you have to force it.

You can take a look at that possible duplicate for further explanation: [Git push rejected after feature branch rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939977/git-push-rejected-after-feature-branch-rebase)

Answer (score 0):

You can also

> git push origin +my_branch

This will make sure all the commits done by you in my_branch are at the top than the commits from rebasing.