# Once again: fast-forward error

Tags: git, fast-forward

So I rebased a branch against the master. However,

```
git push --set-upstream origin MyBranch
```

I get

```
 ! [rejected]        MyBranch -> MyBranch (non-fast-forward)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://mygit@bitbucket.org/mygit/myproject.git'
 hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
 hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
 hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

So, ok. Rebased again. Completed without issue. Then

```
 git pull

 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Ok, Already up to date

```
git push --set-upstream origin MyBranch
```

Again, the error. I could force push, but I don't like the risk of losing things and to be honest, I would really like to know a proper solution for this annoying issue that seems to happen even if I play by the rulebook.

Comment: The branch you rebased had been already pushed?

Comment: Do `git fetch` and `git rebase origin/MyBranch`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push rejected after feature branch rebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939977/git-push-rejected-after-feature-branch-rebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I'm going to try and make an educated *guess* on what might have likely happened.

Git refuses to push your rebased commits into the upstream branch (`origin/MyBranch`) because they have *a different commit hash* than the ones that are already there. They're different because you *rebased your local commits on top of a different commit* than the one that's in the upstream branch.

#### The problem

Here's an example of how I think your situation might look like:

```
      Local                                Origin
A---B---C---F (master)                A---B---C---F (master)
            \                                 \
             D'---E' (MyBranch)                D---E (MyBranch)
```

1. The commits `D` and `E` in `origin/MyBranch` were originally based on top of `C` from `master`. Then `F` became the new `HEAD` of `master`.
2. When you did `git pull` in `master` you got the new commit `F` on your local repo.
3. You rebased `MyBranch` on top of `master`, which is now `F`, and that changed the commits hashes of `D` and `E` into `D'` and `E'`.
4. Issuing `git push origin MyBranch` refuses to overwrite the commits because Git sees them as *different commits* than the ones in `origin`, which are still based on top of `C`.

#### The (possible) solution

If you're the only one working on `MyBranch` or if you can easily communicate with *anyone* that might be interested in doing work in that branch, I say just force push your rebased commits. Again, assuming nobody else has pushed commits to `origin/MyBranch` in the meantime, you won't lose anything.

If this doesn't reflect your situation at all, please feel free to ignore this advice and, if possible, add more details about the problem.