# git fetch changes from ahead upstream and merge them into ahead origin

Tags: git, github

I forked a repository using github, then cloned it locally on my machine.

```
git clone https://github.com/username/nasaproject.git
```

Thus, the local repo has as origin my remote github repo. I also added as upstream the original repository:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/boss/nasaproject.git
```

Running **git branch -a** returns:

```
master
* working_branch
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/working_branch
remotes/upstream/master
remotes/upstream/working_branch
```

On the local repo, I made several changes, committed and pushed them to the origin. At this stage, my github remote repo showed three commits ahead of the original repo.

Few days later, several changes were committed to the original repo. Github shows:

> This branch is 3 commits ahead, 4 commits behind *boss:working_branch*

I would like to merge these changes to my remote repo. This are the steps I done:

```
git status
git stash
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/working_branch
git pull —rebase
git stash pop
```

The local repo shows:

> Your branch is ahead of 'upstream/working_branch’ by 3 commits

and

> Your branch and 'origin/working_branch’ have diverged,
>   and have 7 and 3 different commits each, respectively.

Now, I got confused. How do I update my github repo or origin?

PS: Normally, the below command would do the job.

```
git push origin working_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you did a rebase, you would need to do a force push

```
git push --force origin working_branch
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939977/git-push-rejected-after-feature-branch-rebase) a link to a SO question that does a great job of explaining the issue.