# Git push branch error after pull rebase

Tags: git

step 1. `git pull --rebase`

step 2: `git push origin my_branch`

I get push failed error. If I push branch after removing remote branch then no error.

Question, how to push branch after pull rebase?

Thanks

Comment: Can you type `git branch -vv` and let us know what remote branch is being tracked by `my_branch`?  Normally, you should not see such an error when rebasing on your own branch.

Comment: One possibility is that someone made a new commit to `my_branch` between the time you rebased and the time when you tried to push.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you right. I am rebasing from another branch and there are latest commits too. I am checking and will update you

Comment: Ok your answer was correct. Right now I tried git push --force origin my_branch and it worked without error. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: But beware...force pushing has consequences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push rejected after feature branch rebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939977/git-push-rejected-after-feature-branch-rebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebasing a branch in Git may involve *rewriting* the history of that branch, assuming that the bases of the two branches were different.  From what you told us, it seems that you rebased on a different branch.  Most likely, in your case, your `my_branch` was rewritten, which means you cannot simply push to the remote.

To get around this, you can force push your branch via:

```
git push --force origin my_branch
```

However, you might not want to do this if the rebase on a different branch were unintentional.

Instead, try rebasing this way:

```
git pull --rebase origin my_branch
# resolve merge conflicts, if any
git push origin my_branch
```

**General warning:**

Force pushing a public shared branch is usually a bad idea, because it causes problems for *everyone* who shares that branch.  If your current workflow involves doing this, you might want to reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to check the status of rebase process. If rebase is running push wouldn't work. So **git rebase --abort/ git rebase --skip**  to stop the rebase.
Then try to commit any untracked files if any mismatch.

Finally git push origin my_branch will work I think.

Comment: I will definitely try your solution and will update you . Thanks a lot