# Combine 2 git commits when previous was pushed

Tags: git

How do I combine 2 commits into one when the previous one was already pushed?

Step 1

```
git add file.txt
git commit
git push
```

Step 2

```
git add file.txt
git commit
```

Comment: Be careful with this if you have other developers who may have pulled the published commit. Best practice is not to alter commits that have already been pushed. Doing so will “rewrite history” and require extra work for others working on the project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to combine commits and push to the remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491446/how-to-combine-commits-and-push-to-the-remote)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+combine+commits

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using rebasing. Squash the last two commits with `git rebase -i HEAD~2`.
Then do a force push with `git push --force`**.

** Generally you should prefer `--force-with-lease` over `--force`. If someone else were to push to the branch you are pushing `--force` would overwrite their changes.  `--force-with-lease` would only force push if no one else has pushed to that branch.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit -m "Your new message"
git push --force
```

What this does:

1. Reset your current branch (moves `HEAD`) to antepenultimate commit (the one before the penultimate, represented by `HEAD~2`) but leaves the index and the working tree.
2. This allows to re-stage these changes and commit them in a brand new commit.
3. `--force` allows you to push this new commit and force an override.

---

#### NOTE

As others have commented on your original question, beware that `--force` will most likely annoy other people that have already pulled the previous version of this branch. You could "squash" these changes into a new branch and publish it separately:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git checkout -b my-new-clean-branch
git commit -m "Your new message"
git push -u origin HEAD
```

This way you don't need to `--force` anything.

Comment: You should probably include an explanation about the effects this will have on other developers who may have pulled the branch.

Comment: Squashing into a new branch just duplicates the changes in two different commits. The OP and other visitors should just be aware that a force push can cause problems for others who pulled the branch. Squashing should only be used when no one else is on the same branch

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The idea here is that you could "abandon" the previous branch and start a new independent history. Also, you are truly committing the combined changes of 2 commits into a single one, which is what was asked how to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
git add file.txt
git commit --amend
git push --force
```

The [usual warnings](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---force) about `--force` apply.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these commands in order.

`git add .`

`git commit --amend`

`git push origin <branch> -f`