# Git - Merging release branch into master

Tags: git

I have a master branch and release branches in my git repository which is hosted on bitbucket. I got a merge conflict when I merged release branch r1 into master. The merge conflict was only due to a read me text file. I want to keep the readme file of r1 and reject the one in master.

I fixed the conflict and got an error when I pushed the merged code - "branch can only be modified through pull requests". I know this happens because we are not allowed to push directly into master. How do I merge r1 into master in this case ?

Comment: why not merge master to r1 and then raise a PR ?

Comment: @karthick - I am new to git and not sure how the merging would work in that case. Would r1 changes be replaced by old master code ? I would like to keep only the readme from r1 and reject the readme which is in master.

Answer (score 0):

You should to update the `r1` branch with `master`. And then merge `r1` into `master` using "Pull Request".

There are two ways to update `r1`:

1. Merge `master` into `r1`

   ```
        git checkout r1 // checkout to branch r1
        git fetch origin master // fetch the latest version of master from origin
        git merge origin/master // merge the latest version of master into r1 branch
        git push // push new version of r1 to remote repository
   ```
2. Rebase `r1` on `master`

   ```
        git checkout r1 // checkout to branch r1
        git fetch origin master // fetch the latest version of master from origin
        git rebase origin/master // rebase r1 branch on the latest version of master
        git push --force // push new version of r1 to remote repository
   ```

   why `--force`? see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940299/5599567)