# git squash for remote commit

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I commited and upload the change to bitbucket 
like and commits are like:

```
change3
change2
change1
```

now i wanted to squash the 3 and 2 in to change 1 :`git rebase -i HEAD~3`
then squash the commits into change1.

its ok for local but when i want to push the squash commit it shows 
my remote is ahead of my current push. That's  obvious i think as my
remote has change3 and change2.

so My question is am i using squash in wrong way ?
like in my situation when i want to squash already push commit into one 
how should i do it ?

I am very eager to know the right say of squash already push commit.
TIA.

Comment: Using “stash” here is misleading/incorrect, as that refers to “git stash”, specifically. Updating to use “squash” or “rewrite history” here will lead to better question/reception and results.

Comment: Anyway, the drawback of force pushing a remote (or “rewriting remote history”) is that it may confuse and/or impede others - this is problematic on a mainline which others have already branched from (or merged back into). I would say: 1) don’t rewrite mainline history, and 2) have an agreement with team for rewriting history on work branches. I rewrite and force-push work branches frequently. However, I also try to minimize remote changes by keeping almost all rewriting local.

Comment: Yes, also usually, you need `-f` to force push your rebased changes because when you do `git rebase` you are essentially rewriting history and what has already been committed. So it's a preventive way to let you know that this will overwrite/modify your commits.

Comment: Here's a really nice answer for the same. I hope it helps! :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939977/git-push-rejected-after-feature-branch-rebase#:~:text=If%20you%20rebase%20a%20branch,rebase%20will%20be%20quite%20unpleasant.

Comment: I squash and run 
"git push -f origin branch_name"

but got following error:

remote: Signed commits and tags are enforced for this repository.
remote: d8d6019f2e8 was not signed.
To ssh://git.XXX.com:AAAA/gen/xxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] branch_name -> branch_name (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git.XXX.com:AAAA/gen/xxx.git'