# Git - How to retrieve all new commits from master to my branch

Tags: git

I have a master, from which I created another branch, and did some commits on this new branch.
Meanwhile some other work/commits has also been happening in master at thesame time.

So, I now want to get all the latest updates (commits) that has happened in master into my branch. How do i go about this?

Comment: You should look into [merging](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/291/merging#t=201708231048567374741)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Git branches from master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876977/update-git-branches-from-master)

Answer (score 1):

**Rebase**

Grab your branch and connect it to top of current master by:

```
git rebase master
```

(while being in the branch you want to update)