# How to get changes in a local branches in git?

Tags: git, github

Hi Currently I am using git for managing my source code.

I have currently a master branch and develop branch. i usually creates a feature branch from from develop, works on it and then merge back to develop .

How can i get the latest changes on develop branch to other local branches.

in other words if i have two feature branch B1 and B2 both checked from develop . i did some commits on B1 and then merged B1 to develop . How can i get changes from develop branch to my feature branch B2 ?

thank you .

Comment: yes you are right . i corrected the mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Git branches from master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876977/update-git-branches-from-master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could **merge** or **rebase**.

**MERGE**

```
git fetch # make sure origin/develop is up to date
git checkout B2
git merge origin/develop # merge changes from origin/develop into your branch
```

PRO:

- you don't need to rewrite your B2 history

CONTRA:

- you might need to solve conflicts in the merge commit which makes it more difficult to trace changes back, and to know who was responsible.
- this produces a more complex history

**REBASE**

```
git fetch # make sure origin/develop is up to date
git checkout B2
git rebase origin/develop # rebase your B2 branch on the "new" develop branch
```

PRO:

- you get a clean "semi-linear" git history
- all changes are traceable to a single development branch. No merge commit with changes that belong to both features

CONTRA:

- rewriting history isn't always intuitive
- you change your history, so if other people work on the same branch, the references change. I consider this ok if I am the only person working on my branch. If other people work on the branch, rewriting history is NOT OK (eg on **develop** or **master** branch)