# What do I have to do after a merge?

Tags: git, github

On my git repository, i have 2 branch :

- dev
- match

My "dev" branch is like my master, i merge my other branch on it.

I work on "match", and to merge on my dev, i had switch on it and make "git merge match". The merge is done now.

My question is, **how copy/past the files on the "dev" branch on my "match" branch** ? 2 others developers work on other branch and they did fewmerge before me, i must use the recent files from the dev branch on my match branch

---

I have to make a "git merge dev" ?

Comment: Your title asks what to do _after_ a merge, but your post seems to ask _how_ to merge. This is all covered very well in a great many tutorials. What's the actual problem?

Comment: Also, forget "copy/pasting" files altogether in git context. You'll never need that. git provides great tools to track content. Yes, just merge `dev` back into your `match` branch and you'll get their recent work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, you want to update your working branch "match" with the new files / changes that have been made on the master "dev" branch.

You can either git merge (creating a new merge commit) or rebase, as is described in the below answer:

[Update Git branches from master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876977/update-git-branches-from-master)