# "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'" displayed while attempting to push to git

Tags: github

I am a bit new working with GitHub and have a repo set up to push my project into. Up until recently I have been able to push the project from my laptop to the repo using:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push
```

However, after performing those commands, I now get "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'" every time even though there are changes in my project locally.

I have looked this up and seen similar issues and have attempted:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
git status
```

I still get that my branch is up to date. The only other option I found was to create a new repo to store my project in. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the output of `git status` and `git branch`

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the master first and then update your branche.

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876977/update-git-branches-from-master @HossamAlsheikh

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, I only have one branch available so this did not solve my problem.