# How can I get updated code on Gitlab from a branch to my branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm working on my branch named "hiep". On Gitlab, the "main" branch of my Teacher's repository has a new file. How can I get these new files to my branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Git branches from master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876977/update-git-branches-from-master).

Comment: Note, that linked question and answers specify `origin/master` but you can use the same answer for any remote branch name (e.g. `origin/main` etc.) Also, some of the answers explain that you can use `merge` or `rebase`, and some mention `merge` as the first option. My personal preference would strongly lean towards `rebase` over `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fetch the new commits using

`git fetch origin main`

where `origin` refers to the remote branch from where you want to fetch the changes.

Comment: Git fetch only checks for changes in origin, to actually retrieve the file your teacher added you need to git pull

Comment: @ffm_nosoup Umm, if so, then is this answer wrong? Would be really glad if you could point this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch