# How to merge a file in dev branch to master branch

Tags: git

I am new to git.  I and working in the dev branch.  I need to merge one file to the master branch in my local repo and then check in the master.  How do I do that?

I see this on guthub cheat sheet but qiute to nkt see the logic.

```
git merge laptop/xyz
```

So if file myfile then

```
git merge myfile master/origin?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below steps :

```
1) git branch
* master
  your_new_brach
2) git checkout your_new_brach my_file1 my_file2 my_file3
3) git status # You will see new changes into master branch 
4) git commit -m "'Merge' changes from 'your_new_brach' branch"
```

I think link is similar to your problem :
[How do you merge selective files with git-merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge)

Comment: check the link : http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/