# How can I retain one file's conflicting changes from a pulled 'theirs' branch when using `git pull -s ours`?

Tags: git, integration

I have to get some changes from a developer. Because I do not want to perform manual merging  I do:

```
git pull -s ours origin developers_branch
```

The problem is sometimes I need all changes in a particular file (i.e. to do merging if there are conflicts).

So the question is how to obtain all changes (ignoring emerging conflicts in my favor) except for a particular file.

Comment: How would you determine which conflicts you should see and which you shouldn't?

Comment: I am interested in particular changes. For instance our designer changes CSS styles in the file main.css. I need those changes because my ongoing work depends on them. In addition I would like to get other changes without merging so I wont probably get any trouble in the future.The oftener you merge the less problems you have.

Comment: In that particular case, the designer could stage just the CSS files, commit and push

Comment: It is sometimes true "the more often you merge, the fewer problems you have". That doesn't apply as neatly to merges with `-s ours`. You're abandoning other contributor's changes when conflicts arise. Unless your workflow takes that into account, it'll cause trouble at integration time and might result in broken code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `--no-commit` option, then make appropriate changes (undo changes in the file, etc), then `git commit`.

Also, worth to mention a better approach: split the changes in different commits/branches: which require merge and which don't require. After it you could do merges easily.

Comment: Would this work? Does the `-s ours` merge strategy abandon the changes *after* `--no-commit` would operate?

Comment: Oh, I missed this part. You can omit `-s ours`, merge all, and before the commit revert all changes except in the file.

Comment: @Christopher This is answer which describes this approach step-by-step http://stackoverflow.com/a/7292109/438742