# how to merge specific files in git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Suppose I have a project on MASTER branch with 100s of php files. To do a bug fixing in the project, i create a separate branch

```
git checkout -b bugfix
```

Then after fixing the bug in 3 files (for eg index.php, register.php and login.php), i merge it in the master branch

```
git checkout master
git merge bugfix
```

The above code will merge all the 3 files i made changes, but is there anyway that i can force GIT to merge only 2 files, say login.php and register.php only?

Comment: I think one way would be to commit those two files in one commit and the last in the other, I think you can specify a commit and merge just that one.

Comment: @dutt The OPs problem is that the file changes are already committed, I asume.

Comment: Maybe this can help to find a way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge

Comment: Are you sure, that you really want a workflow which Git was not optimized for? To me it feels like you should change your workflow and create two bugfix branches, if you intend to merge them separately.

Answer (score 15):

There are two approaches:

---

## Approach 01

The following solution is adopted from [a blog post](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/)

It turned out that checkout can also be helpful in this matter. You can simply callout (checkout) those specific files from another branch:

```
# switch to the branch you want to be your merge destination
git checkout master

# checkout specific files from specific branch (e.g bugfix)
# format: git checkout <source branch> <file.1> <file.2> ... <file.N>
git checkout bugfix login.php register.php

# check the status
git status

# merge them in
git commit -m "your merge comment"
```

---

## Approach 02

This is an easy **alternative approach**, but it only works if you have one commit per file (meaning every time you have changed a file, you have made one commit and then have moved to the next file). In this case you can simply bring those specific commits to the other branch (in your case the master branch):

```
# get which commit you want to take to the other branch (first 7 characters will do)
git log

# switch to the branch you want to be your merge destination
git checkout master

# bring specific commit to this branch (replace the 63344f2 with your own 7 character commit ID)
git cherry-pick 63344f2
```

Comment: It doesn't merge the branch into `master`.

Comment: @axiac if you read the question carefully you will realise that the question is not about merging a branch, it is about merging a file (which is a wrong terminology for bringing a specific file from another branch to the desired branch). The solution above works

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to record a partial merge in Git, all merges must merge the entire root trees of all the commits being merged.

You can of course choose to resolve that merge by choosing the unchanged copy of one the files from one of the parents, but this is still a "full" merge and the changes in that file will be considered to have been merged when it comes to subsequent rebases or merges between the branches involved.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the behaviour you want but what happens with the changes you did on the third file?

The changes on the third file remain in the commits on the branch but they will not be present in the merged commit, it's like the file was not modified on the branch at all.

This is how you can do it:

```
git checkout master
git merge bugfix --no-commit
```

The `--no-commit` option tells `git` to merge the files but stop before committing them. You can now inspect the files, change them, do whatever you want. In order to cancel the changes you did on `index.php` you can run:

```
git checkout master -- index.php
```

Running `git status` you can see that `index.php` does not appear as modified any more (neither in the index or in the working tree). You can now `git commit` and that's all.

Comment: This solution is like changing all the files and then try to manually correct the mess !! read [this post](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/) to get what this stack is about and why your solution is waste of time and labour work.

Answer (score 0):

No, there doesn't exist a direct way. Though; you can select the files from branch you want to merge and overwrite them over existing ones in master branch. The commands in order shall be:

```
git checkout master
git show bugfix:login.php > login.php
git show bugfix:register.php > register.php
git add .
git commit -m "Select login and register from branch/bugfix"
```

---

Ok, the above method will "destroy" file history. There is an old discussion about the same in [this mailing list](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0701/37964.html).

> From a technical standpoint, the thing that makes history matter (and
>   why  "set of commits in date order" is useless) is because it gives us
>   a COMMON  ANCESTOR! And *that* is the only thing that matters.
>
> Now, what is fundamentally wrong with doing per-file history?
>
> Now, if you've followed this argument, you should go "Aaahh!
>   Obvious!".

Ignoring a whole lot of paragraphs; you'll find the workaround:

```
git diff commit..othercommit filename | git-apply --index && git commit
```

In your case, `commit` = hash of you HEAD/master branch; and `othercommit` = hash of bugfix branch.

Comment: It doesn't merge the branch into `master`.