# Git selectively mege via rebase, but old commits still show as unmerged on next rebase

Tags: git, github

Here's the scenario:

I have a development branch and a master branch. There were a few checkins on development I did not want to merge into master, so I followed the instructions here to selectively merge from development (via rebase):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/891222/762238

Development was ahead of master by a lot of commits, and during the rebase, there were several commits (e.g. A,B,C) that resulted in conflicts, which I resolved and committed.

Now those same commits (A,B,C) show up every time I try to do another selective merge or merge all from development.

Is there a way for these commits to not show up during merge, as I've already conflict resolved and merged them into master?

(Note, I've tried to cherry pick these commits and merge them in again a second time. After resolving conflicts, git shows that there is nothing to commit as I had already resolved and committed them to master the first time - strange ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tag after the last rebase on development, e.g. last_rebase. Then in the next rebase you can use:

```
git rebase -i last_rebase --onto master
```

and after you have successfully committed them on master you can move the tag with

```
git tag -f last_rebase
```

so that with the next commit, only the new ones show up.

Comment: Ok, this would help with the rebase, but suppose I want to do:

`git merge development`

Wouldn't those old commits still show up again?

Comment: yes, merging and rebasing are two different things. If you want to avoid that some commits from development get merged, you can create a dummy merge commit with: "git merge -s ours development".  Then, with the next merge, only new commits from development get merged.