# Is there a form to do checkout of a specific folder from other branch to my branch by git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

I'm working with git and each developer has yours branches with new features separately, so I want just merge a piece of code (folder) to my branch.

Comment: Even if you could I don't think that would be a good workflow.

Comment: you should be merging commits and not folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this link [How do you merge selective files with git-merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge). It may help you. its about selective merging so you can try to merge only that folder.