# Merging everything from one branch to master except one file in Git

Tags: git

I have a website I'm working on that contains the "master" branch, which is exactly what is on the server, and a branch called "development", where I code new features before merging it into master.

The problem is that I have a file that should be different in both versions (`.htaccess`). Is there a way to merge everything from "development" to "master", **except** `.htaccess`?

Comment: You can [Cherry-pick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge) it.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge

Answer (score 0):

I'd add `.htaccess` to your `.gitignore` file.  It might make deploying a bit more difficult, but it'll be *much* better than cherry picking it out every time.

Keep in mind you'll need to remove `.htaccess` from the index (`git rm --cached`) in order for this to take effect.

Comment: This is the correct way to do this, but there's a step you left out. Adding .htaccess to your .gitignore file means git will not track changes to this file. That means if you need it to change as part of your deploy or merge you will need a script that alters it on that event. If it needs to be different based on the branch itself, look into git hooks. If it needs to be different once you deploy it to an environment, there are other options at your disposal. Perhaps leaving it the correct value on the destination environment.

Comment: @BrianMego My approach would probably be to have a `development.htaccess` file, and a `production.htaccess` file, and copy or symlink `.htaccess` to `production.htaccess` as part of the build/deploy.

Answer (score 0):

The unintended problem with most merge processes that you will run into at this point is that your `.htaccess` is already part of the development history, i.e. even if you remove now, and then merge the history of your `.htaccess` will exist in the history of master.

If this is a one-time merge, I would squash your development into master and remove the `.htaccess` at that time, i.e.:

```
git merge --squash development
```

This will stage every file that that is different in your development branch to be committed as a single commit onto master. Now you can remove .htaccess

```
git reset .htaccess
git checkout .htaccess
```

The first line will unstage your changes, the second will remove the modifications. Now you can commit your changes