# Choose what to merge from a fork to a parent repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge

I'm using SourceTree with Bitbucket and I've created a fork from an original repository and I'm using the tool 'compare' to merge changes from the forked repo to the original.
The problem is that Bitbucket only let's me merge all the files at once and I need to have some control over what files should be merged and what files shouldn't.

Is there a way to exclude files from the merge? Or even specific lines of code from certain files?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to make, in your local clone of your fork, a branch where you make the merge, comparing your patch branch with `upstream/master` (You can add the remote upstream referencing the url of the original repo).

That branch starts from `upstream/master`.
You merge your patch branch and upstream/master using one of the [selective merge techniques described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449541/6309).

Then you push that merged branch to your fork, and do a PR from there.