# How can I merge a file history from a branch to another in git?

Tags: git, git-merge

So first check the following image, I tried to represent what I need
[image: git situation]

The green squares are the commits, and the yellow, brown and red are parts of those commits (in my case commits to specifically 3 files spread through the commits).

There are no further changes made on dev

What actually happened: I was working on a branch and found out that some changes were actually useful on the `dev` branch and were not actually related to the `dev2` branch. So I wanted that those changes on the `dev` branch.

```
git checkout
git merge
```

I actually want the modifications to get out of the `dev2` branch and go into the `dev` branch, so if I do the checkout>commit the modifications will be on both branches, that's why I wouldn't like to do it.

Is this even possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can just find the `sha` of the last commit that should be in dev (the red square) by using `git log`, and then go to your master branch `checkout master` and just say `git merge SHA` where SHA of the red square. This is quite a common thing in git. It happens a lot with forked repos, to merge in the updates of the original.

Remember though that this gets the whole commits, i am not sure if that is what you want. If you want just some files from those commits, it will be a lot harder. Then you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge).

Comment: I don't want the whole commits, just some part of it, as I tried to explain I want that all the modifications done to 3 files go to the dev branch, and that they will not appear in the dev2 branch, if that is even possible. but it seems that I will have to go with the checkout>commit way

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You need to do three things:

- Checkout the original branch: `git checkout dev`
- Apply the commits that you want: `git cherry-pick yellow`, `git cherry-pick brown`, `git cherry-pick red`
- Rebase `dev2` onto `dev`: `git checkout dev2`, `git rebase --onto dev`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but yellow,brown,red are parts of a commit, not single commits, so cherry pick will get all changes from those commits and not just the things I need

Comment: In that case, you will have to do those changes manually. You can do a cherry-pick, reset one step back (i.e. HEAD^) and then do git checkout -- files-you-want-to-restore and use `git status` to figure out which parts you want to keep and which you don't - but you're going to end up with a different commit in any case so there's no difference with doing that and with doing it by hand. This is also why it makes sense to commit individual commits separately instead of all in one giant go, so you can cherry pick efficiently.

Comment: surely I didn't commit correctly, I surely should have not commited those files thogheter and should have created a separate commit