# Git exclude files from merging and history

Tags: git

With git, I want to replace all the files, except some specific ones, in branch A with the same files from branch B.

I don't want to merge because I don't want branch A to have the history of these specific files from B.

I have lost several hours and made many tests and didn't find the answer. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you either have to have all of the history of B or none of the history of B; I assume you want the latter.

First, while on branch A, do `git checkout B .` (make sure to include the period at the end). This will overwrite all the files in your working directory with those from B. Then, for each file you *don't* want from B, do `git checkout A /path/to/filename`. This will "un overwrite" those files. Then commit, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the usual merge, since you don't the history from A to go into B you can use [squashing-commits-with-rebase](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) so it will be 1 commit inthe hisotry

Comment: I'm using answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7292109/2235673 to select the files. How should I commit to avoid including in the history the files that I don't want to be included?